# jQuery - if else statement regarding radio buttons

Tags: jquery

I have 2 radio buttons for yes and no, i was wondering if it is possible to run an if else statement in jQuery to see if one or the other is pressed?

```
<input type="radio" name="option" value="yes">
<input type="radio" name="option" value="no">
```

if yes is selected then do this else if no is selected do something else

Is that possible in jQuery?

Comment: not my design, im only continuing development

Comment: so despite the fact that you agree it's wrong your not going to correct it while your working on the code anyhow ?

Answer (score 3):

You can write

```
if ($('input:radio[name="option"]:checked').val() === "yes")
```

However, you should use a single checkbox instead.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
if ( $('[type=radio]').filter(':checked').length)
```

Comment: That's unnecessarily slow; a tag filter is much faster.  Also, that doesn't check which one is checked.

Answer (score 0):

After checkign Slaks answer, and re-reading the question

```
var result = $('input:radio[name="option"]:checked').val();
if (result === 'yes') {
}else if (result === 'no') {
}
```

that way you aren't running to same query twice or duplicating code